# How to get access to user\APPDATA\LOCAL folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, administrator, local

We are building an application for Windows 7 that creates some data files that the user will occasionally want to review and a log file that we might need for support.  Our first version is writing the files to `USER\APPDATA\LOCAL\ourprogam folder`.  I thought we had solved our problems until I installed it in a user account that is not an administrator and now I can't find the folder and don't see a way to make it accessible to the user.

So my question boils down to how do I get access to the `APPDATA` folder in Windows 7?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Burch If you solved it, you can answer your own question by using the "answer your question" button below. Don't put the *answer* into the *question* please.

Comment: @KCo Why, if I may ask? A problem with not seeing a folder in Windows doesn't belong here?

Comment: @slhck Because installer routines and how they work are more up their ally.

Comment: @KCotreau That's not what [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) is about.

Comment: This is not a [programmers.se] question. It's not even remotely related to programmers or programming. See their [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already said, the problem is in settings under Windows Explorer -> Organize -> Folder and search options -> View -> under Hidden files and folders check Show hidden files, folders and drives.

Answer (score 8):

Here's another way to access this location even when the Windows Explorer view options are set to hide this path otherwise assuming you already have appropriate access already.

1. Click **Start**, go to **Run**, type in  **`%localappdata%`**, and press <kbd>**Enter**</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>**Win**</kbd>+<kbd>**R**</kbd>, type in **`%localappdata%`**, and press <kbd>**Enter**</kbd>

Tested in Windows 7, 8.1, and 10